# Convert HttpResponseMessage to HttpResponseData to return from azure function

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, httpresponse

I have an azure function .net5 .In this function I use httpclient created by IHttpClientFactory. HttpClient methods like post,put etc. return **HttpResponseMessage**  .I need to return this data from azure function. But the azure function has HttpResponseData as the return type. Bellow you can find a simple code.

```
[Function("azurefunction")]
public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Admin, "post")] HttpRequestData req,
FunctionContext executionContext)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync("GetItems", content);
    **return response; // here is the issue**
}
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: I think you have to manually copy over `Headers`, `StatusCode` and `Body`. I'm unaware of any built-in conversion method.